# Heroku: python app works locally but does't on remote after git push

Tags: python, heroku, redis, heroku-redis

I'm trying to deploy a python app that supports redis and I'm currently facing a problem.
I have two git branches, one for production and one for dev and two different heroku apps (python-app, dev-python-app). My git repos are:

```
git remote
heroku
heroku-test
```

I use the fallowing commands to deploy the heroku-test to check if the app works correctly before passing to prod:

```
git branch dev-python-app
git add .
git commit -m "commit msg"
git push heroku-test dev-python-app:master
```

It says that everything's ok: "remote: Verifying deploy... done." but the app won't start.
If I check logs with: `heroku logs --tail -a dev-python-app`:

```
2022-02-09T10:36:29.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user *****
2022-02-09T10:36:53.638128+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 267f3889 by user ****
2022-02-09T10:36:53.638128+00:00 app[api]: Release v21 created by user ****
2022-02-09T10:37:02.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
```

The stange thing is that if I run a one-off dyno using `heroku run bash -a dev-python-app` and than start the python app as: `python3 main.py` it works perfectly.

Moreover, It'd be useful to know that I tried this mentioned steps before introducing redis support to the app and It worked perfectly so could be redis the problem?

What do you think? Thank you

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with Git. Git does not implement Heroku. Heroku simply *uses* Git as a transport system. You can write code that works locally but not elsewhere, and send it around with Git and it will work locally and not elsewhere, not because of Git, but because it works locally and not elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed that.
The problem was to scale the working process:

```
heroku ps:scale worker=1 -a dev-python-app
```